# Why does this parser not find the contents of the XML tag that uses a namespace prefix?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have this XML code, drawn from [this link](https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:nyt="http://www.nytimes.com/namespaces/rss/2.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title>‘This Did Not Go Well’: Inside PG&amp;E’s Blackout Control Room</title>
      <dc:creator>Ivan Penn</dc:creator>
      <pubDate>Sat, 12 Oct 2019 17:03:11 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

When I try to parse it using `lxml` and following the [documentation for xpath and XML namespaces](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes), the parser finds the title (which doesn't use a namespace) but not the authors/creators, which does:

```
from lxml import html

xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:nyt="http://www.nytimes.com/namespaces/rss/2.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title>‘This Did Not Go Well’: Inside PG&amp;E’s Blackout Control Room</title>
      <dc:creator>Ivan Penn</dc:creator>
      <pubDate>Sat, 12 Oct 2019 17:03:11 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
"""


rss = html.fromstring(xml)
items = rss.xpath("//item")
for item in items:
    title = item.xpath("title")[0].text_content().strip()
    print(title)

    ns = {"dc" : "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"}
    authors = item.xpath("dc:creator", namespaces = ns)
    print(authors)
```

This code prints:

> This Did Not Go Well’: Inside PG&E’s Blackout Control Room
>   []

Since it finds the contents of the title tag correctly I think it's finding the individual `<item>` tags. Is there something wrong with how I'm passing the namespace to `xpath`?

EDIT: The result is the same whether or not I use the trailing slash, i.e.

```
ns = {"dc" : "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"}
ns = {"dc" : "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1"}
```

Comment: Why do you parse RSS (which is XML) with the `lxml.html.fromstring`? Have you tried to use lxml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Lack of experience with XML/lxml is the only reason (and not a good one, I know). I'll look into `etree` too. I'll google it too but would the code be pretty similar to this?

Comment: Yes, use `from lxml import etree as ET` and then `rss = ET.parse('https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml')`, at least if the URL is right.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'll try that. The URL is correct, but there are additional errors with the `parse` function (or with `ET.XML` called on a string) but that's a separate/different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML parser ignores namespaces. This is the last sentence in the [Running HTML doctests](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#running-html-doctests) section in the lxml documentation:

> The HTML parser notably ignores namespaces and some other XMLisms.

[Another part](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html) of the documentation says:

> Also note that the HTML parser is meant to parse HTML documents. For XHTML documents, use the XML parser, which is namespace aware.

It will work if you change

```
authors = item.xpath("dc:creator", namespaces = ns)
```

to

```
authors = item.xpath("creator")
```

But since RSS is not HTML, consider using the XML parser (`from lxml import etree`).